# Attaching event handlers for dynamically created jQuery Mobile pages

Tags: jquery-mobile

In my jQuery Mobile application, I am creating some dynamic pages.Here is the code

```
function createPages()
{
    $header = "<header data-role='header'><h1>Dynamically created pages</h1></header>";
    $content = "<div data-role='content' class='content'><p>This is a dynamically generated page</p></div>";
    $footer = "<div data-role='footer'><h1>Audimax</h1></footer>";

    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
    {   
        $section= "<section id='"+"#fav"+$i+"' data-role='page' data-url='"+"fav"+$i+"' class='dynamic'>";
        $new_page = $($section+$header+$content+$footer+"</section>");
        $new_page.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);

    }
}
```

The pages are being created properly and being added to the DOM and I can navigate to them. The problem is that I simply can,t attach any event handlers to the dynamic pages.I am using ids of the dynamic pages with jquery "live" but to no avail.Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are trying to attach the event and call ?

Comment: Where is you javascript code at? in each new dynamic page? or the page that's first loaded (Where it should be)? http://jsfiddle.net or and example link/code would be nice as well

Answer (score 1):

Why not bind the event handlers when you add the new pseudo-page to the DOM?

```
function pageShowFunction () {
    console.log(this.id + ' has triggered the `pageShow` event!');
}
function createPages()
{
    $header = "...";
    $content = "...";
    $footer = "...";

    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
    {   
        $section= "<section id='"+"#fav"+$i+"' data-role='page' data-url='"+"fav"+$i+"' class='dynamic'>";
        $new_page = $($section+$header+$content+$footer+"</section>").bind('pageshow', pageShowFunction);
        $new_page.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);

    }
}
```

It's normally better to bind directly to elements rather than delegating the event handling.

**P.S.** You didn't post your event binding code so I can't give any specific comments on that code, perhaps you can update your question with that code if this doesn't fix your issue.

Comment: The dynamic pages have ids #fav1,#fav2,#fav3 etc. There is only one single js file and everything is done in it.I trying to attach event handlers to every page simply as:   $("#fav1").live("tap",function(event, ui)
{
 console.log("The click handler is working");
 
});

Comment: Thank you Jasper, your suggestion of binding handlers directly at dynamic page creation is working.

Comment: Any suggestion for how to proceed when changing some markup on the dynamic generated pages?The standard approach using the ids I have mentioned above : $("#fav1 ul").append("<li>123</li>") is not working

Comment: I would have to see the rendered HTML structure after the dynamically generated page is added to the DOM. I can't say for sure how to select the element since I don't know the structure of the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade the jquery core to 1.7.1 from
http://jquery.com/download/

and then

```
$(selector).live( eventName, function(){} );
```

Can be replaced with the following on signature

```
$(document).on( eventName, selector, function(){} );
```

It then works for dynamic elements.